# Highcharts Chart of column type is not working in gwt

Tags: gwt-highcharts

In column chart, if chart is dynamic then it not works in chrome.
In all other browser it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by changing all the width and height parameters from percentage to pixel values.